# Focusing light through fiber optic cable to extend telescope viewer

Tags: telescope, telescope-lens

I want to build a system to view my telescope without being uncomfortable. Currently I have to stand up and bend over to view the eye piece.

I want to build a system that allows me to 'pipe' the output of the view piece in a non-digital format along a flexible fiber optic cable to my eye and possible split the view into two for a sort of VR headset.

I know the cable will transfer the light, but will it be just burly light or break down too much (one meter or less) or will I be able to focus it into view-able picture?

I could just try it, but the cable itself is really expensive to get, and I want to know if this is worth trying before I spend.

I'm thinking of using [this 14 mm 'solid core' cable](http://www.wiedamark.com/14mmsolidcoreendfiberopticcable-1.aspx)

Comment: I don't think this will really work out how you want it to.  Fiber optic cables are designed to send information as an abstraction of optics, not an actual optical image. Fiber optics do nothing to preserve the image, they just pass the light itself along.  If you want to preserve the image, you need mirrors (and probably lenses).

Comment: Agree with @MitchGoshorn. You need to set up a camera at the telescope focus and then "pipe" the output from that.

Comment: @MitchGoshorn yeah, I was afraid of that. though the cord I linked is not fiber optic per say, More like clear plastic. the mirrors and lenses approach would be ideal, but complicated to build. :P @-Rob, yeah I didn't want to go digital though, I may as well just use Google Space :P

Answer (score 1):

In principle a [fiberscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiberscope) eyepiece could work but not very well.
By putting one end of the cable flush with the field stop of an eyepiece (few allow this) and the other end exactly in the telescope's focal plane, you'd get a fiber-pixelated image.
A binoviewer would require two cables, difficult to align.

Comment: Yes, "fiber-pixelated image". Expensive too.